# What to do if driver's license is lost during road trip?

Tags: united-states, driving

My friend just lost her driver's license in California, during a road trip from Arizona to Oregon.  It's an Arizona license, but she's moving to Oregon.  Since she's moving, she doesn't even have an Arizona address anymore, which probably complicates things.

What does one do in such a situation?  My online research so far has just turned up "you're screwed in that case".

The only option I can think of is to continue driving to Oregon and hope she doesn't get pulled over.  She already got pulled over once, and got away with a warning and a fix-it ticket for the license (that's how she learned it was lost).

Comment: Is she already in Oregon?

Comment: No, she's still in California.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should probably better be asked on Law SE. Flagging for migration.

Comment: I think losing a license or travel document is quite a common thing to happen to travelers, thus on topic

Comment: It's pretty easy to not get pulled over. It does require changing one's driving habits, though...

Comment: To answer my own question, it sounds like you're supposed to hang out in a hotel until you can get a replacement.  Some states (but not Arizona) can fax a temporary license.  She decided to just risk the drive, and made it without getting pulled over.

Answer (score 5):

a quick online search takes me to the DMZ website; [Out-of-State Replacement](http://www.dmv.org/az-arizona/replace-license.php#Out-of-State-or-Military-License-Replacement)

> **Out-of-State or Military License Replacement**
>
> You can replace a lost
>   Arizona license while out of state using the online, telephone, or
>   mail-in options outlined above.
>
> The MVD allows the same processes for military members deployed out of
>   state and their dependents, too. Simply apply for your military
>   replacement license online, by calling the MVD, or by mail—whichever
>   is most convenient for you.
>
> If you apply online, you will need to choose the express delivery
>   option for an additional $16.95 fee (see “Apply Online" above). This
>   option lets you order delivery to an out-of-state address. Otherwise,
>   the duplicate will be sent to the address on file with the MVD.
>
> The out-of-state address you provide for express delivery will NOT
>   appear on your duplicate license or ID, nor will it change the
>   permanent/resident address on file.
>
> Remember, express service is not available for military delivery boxes
>   or P.O boxes (e.g., APO, FPO) and is only available in the U.S.

You can apply online at the [Arizona Department of Transportation](http://servicearizona.com/duplicateLicense).
You do need an address they can send it to, however its likely to take up to 15  You may be able to get it delivered express which may be much faster.

> *How long will it take to get my Duplicate Driver License or Identification Card?*
>
> You will receive your Duplicate Driver License or Identification Card within 15 days.
>
> If you request express delivery, an expedited delivery date will be provided based on the state and zip code of delivery and the time
>   the order is placed.

Given you are on a road trip, this may or may not work for your time frame.  Give it a try and see what the expected date of delivery is.  Otherwise your friend best avoid driving without a license.

**Update**:

She can of course, order a replacement to be sent to her new Oregon address (which she has done).  We can't however advise you on the legality of driving without a license in this scenario.  Obviously there are other ways to continue her journey without driving.

Comment: She ordered a replacement, which will arrive to her Oregon address tomorrow.  In the mean time, she's decided to just try and make it to Oregon without getting pulled over.  She has at least an email confirmation that the replacement license has been ordered.

Answer (score 2):

The State of Arizona allows you to [order a duplicate license online](https://servicearizona.com/driverLicense/duplicate) and have it express-mailed to any address (not necessarily your permanent address.)  The fee works out to be $12 for the duplicate license and $16.95 for express delivery.  So if money and time are no object, the best way to resolve the problem would be to stay in California for a few days, have Arizona send her a new license, and then continue on her way.

This might be tricky if time or money are at a premium, though.

Comment: Time at a premium - possibly.  Money at a premium?  Not sure - definitely cheaper than a $100 or so fine.

Comment: Arizona can provide a license in one day.  Unfortunately there is no way I can talk her into staying in California for a day.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

My wife left her purse on a taxi the day before a flight.  It's not identical to your case, but the airline's advice (to enter the TSA secure area and board) was:

1. Get a police report identifying the loss of the license
2. Use another photo ID or credit card if she didn't have one

Outbound was no issue but on the return trip, the TSA gave the police report and out of state grad student ID a good eyeball (it technically wasn't sufficient as a government ID) but let her board.

A police report identifying the loss of a driver's license is not a driving credential, but it is evidence that the person is on the ball, and that the time window since the loss of the license is at least documented, in the event of getting pulled over in the next 15 days while waiting for the expedited replacement in the other answers.